# How to pass in an array of objects from iOS http call (POST) to NodeJS server

Tags: ios, node.js, rest

I am trying to pass in an array of object something like this from an IOS app to the nodeJS server VIA a http POST, no JSON involved.

My server detects the CompanyId correctly, however, the array of objects it somehow detect it as a string. with lots of `{\n     [{ \n`.

How do I post from iOS in such a way that it can be recognized as an array of objects from server end?

**POST Object**

```
{
    CompanyId : 0293489187454
    Employees:[{
                 Id : 12092834085,
                 FirstName : Samantha,
                 LastName : Trucker
              },
              {
                 Id : 12092834086,
                 FirstName : Bob,
                 LastName : Trucker
              }]
}
```

Comment: How are you detecting the POST object now? Can you include that part of the server code?

Comment: detecting the POST object from the server is purely just `req.body.Employees`

Comment: Is it because the nodeJS can only parse JSON objects?